# String with `\(var)` causes "unwrapping an optional value" error

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uikit

I have a loop like so that creates a string representing a url:

```
    for(var i = 1; i < 6; i++)
    {
        let urlString: String = "http://{...}/data/\(i).txt"
        var downloader = FileDownloader(url: urlString, array: peopleArray, table: theTable)

        downloaderQueue.addOperation(downloader)
    }
```

FileDownloader constructor is as follows:

```
let urlString: String
var personArray: Array<Person> = []
var person: Person
let table: UITableView

init(url: String, array: Array<Person>, table: UITableView)
{
    self.urlString = url
    self.person = Person()
    self.personArray = array
    self.table = table
}
```

When this code runs, lldb gives me the error:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)
```

And I know the problem is the string because of the debugger output:

```
downloader  Lecture_14.FileDownloader   0x000000016fd89f60  0x000000016fd89f60
    Foundation.NSOperation  NSOperation     
    urlString   String  "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" 
        _core   _StringCore
```

Any ideas why this would be happening?

Comment: Which line of code is failing?

Comment: the `var downloader = ...` line

Comment: I don't know Swift, but to me, the error suggests that you're trying to take a value out of the option container without first checking if the operation had failed. Option types are used to represent operations that can fail, and will either return a wrapped result, or a failure object. If you try to unwrap the failure object (nil?), you'll get an exception. If this is the case, you'll need to pattern match against the result and account for failure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Xcode, option-click on each of the variables in use: urlString, peopleArray and theTable.

The popup that appears will show you whether the variable is an optional variable by appending a ? to the class name.

From your code above, urlString should not be an optional and therefore should not be the problem. But check the other variables in use and see if any of them are optionals.

If so, use something like this:

```
if let checkedPeopleArray = peopleArray {
   // now you can use checkedPeopleArray and be sure it is not nil
}
```

A couple of other points to make your code more Swift-like:

Your loop can be written like this, using Swift's range instead of the traditional C-style loop:

```
for i in 1..<6 {
    let urlString: String = "http://{...}/data/\(i).txt"
}
```

When declaring an array, Apple changed this from the first version of Swift. Instead of:

```
var personArray: Array<Person> = []
```

try:

```
var personArray: [Person]()  // empty array for Person objects
```

And in your init:

```
init(url: String, array: [Person], table: UITableView)
```

Functionally the same, but I feel it is better to use the changes to the language as they appear because there is no telling when/if Apple might remove the old syntax.

Comment: Thanks for the style tips. The issue seems to be `theTable`. I need to be able to reload the table data from the NSOperation thread that I'm running. Is there a better way to do that than passing it a UITableView instance?

Comment: How about adding a delegate protocol to your FileDownloader class? When  it has the data ready for the table, it could send it to its delegate to reload the table.